# remove double dots from a string and not the single dot using shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I want to remove **double dot** from a string but **not the single dot** using shell script.

example string: `a..b.c`
expected output: `ab.c`

I tried `tr -d ".."` but its removing all the dots. I tried `tr -d "\.\."` then also same result "`abc`".

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: `sed 's/[.][.]//g' file`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can replace multiple dots with none:

```
sed -E 's/\.\.+//g'
```

Comment: sed 's/\.\.//g' is working. Just need to remove * from sed.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Ok, it's too early in the morning. I've updated my post. Thank you. :)

Comment: Ok, but you still need another cup of coffee. `sed` doesn't support the `+` (one or more occurrences) without the `-E` or `-r` options `:)` You don't need the `+` or `*` since you have `/g`. Just look for two dots.

Comment: Thanks everyone. This one is solving the purpose. Just one more modification, if i need to remove everything after detecting more than 2 dots.

Answer (score 3):

In bash:

```
var=a..b.c
$ echo "${var//../}"
ab.c
```